# Is blocking of unwanted phone calls implementable on iOS?

Tags: ios

I want to drop a particular call if caller number belongs to some 'black-list'.

Is there any such possibility to do this programmatically on iOS (iPhones and iPads)?

From my understanding, such program must be running all the time like system service but I've never seen such apps. If no, then I could run app by myself and put it in background, but will the app from background be able to do this, and finally are there ant methods in API for performing this?

Comment: Not unless you're on a jailbroken phone, and even then I'm not sure. iOS locks down access to core telephone functions - you can't get the call log, you can't see the SMS log or messages.

Comment: google would have been your friend and also would have saved us from having to close this question: 'it isn't a real question'

Answer (score 1):

There's no public APIs for achieving anything like that.

Moreover this is a functionality that Apple will embed in iOS7, as per the last WWDC conference.

Comment: Thanks for info about iOS7!